# ssas dimension duplicate only when using name Value

Tags: ssas

I am new to this.  Been working on a table that is nowhere near normalized, but that is a side note, and I do not know if that is part of the issue.
I am creating a dimension
Dimension is below

- InvoiceItemCode
- MemberNo
- MemberDescription
- OtherItems

I am using the Name Value to display the `MemberDescription` in place of the `InvoiceItemCode` on the report.  But when I do, It gives me a **Duplicate Item** warning.
If I leave it empty it does not.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer.  After a little rubber duck debugging, the question was posed about how does the SQL statement change when the MemberDescription was used.

So following that path, I had found that the changes between the two Statements brought out an issue in the item database and the Keys.

So (simplified)

```
Select distinct InvoiceItemCode + packtype from Items
```

would return 0000CASE

and 
`Select distinct InvoiceItemCode,packtype,invoiceItem+packtype`
would return 
0000 CASE 0000CASE
0000CASE '' 0000CASE

So I found my answer.  I just needed to dig deeper into the sql.
Thank You